# How to use a trained Tensorflow Lite model in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, speech-recognition, tensorflow-lite

I have a **Tensorflow Lite** model (`.tflite` file), which is already trained.

I need to use it in an API Python view that receives recorded `.wav` files for speech recognition, and returns the equivalent text to the recorded file that was sent.

Any advice or tutorials on how I could use the trained model in order to treat the recorded instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [TFLite Inference Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference) for more details.

Specifically, for python refer to [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference#load_and_run_a_model_in_python)